# unity2D Moving to a fixed object causes shaking

Tags: unity-game-engine

Please pay attention to the gif:

[image]

There are two objects.

> left circle object = circle colider2D + rigidbody2D(freeze positionY, freeze Rotation Z, script for move )

Script for move:

```cs
void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") > 0){
        transform.Translate(Vector2.right * 2f * Time.deltaTime);
    }

}
```

> right square object = square colider2D + rigidbody2D(freeze positionY, freeze positionX, freeze Rotation Z)

Moving the left object to the right, when two objects meet, The left object shakes to the left and right. I don't know why.
I hope the two objects do not overlap.

How can I prevent the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using Transform to move non kinematic rigibodies, you should not. Either use `AddForce()` to move your objects, or use kinematic rigidbodies and Translate but that will require a LOT more work as you will need to manage collisions by yourself if you want something clean and smooth.

Comment: And if you do use AddForce, do it in FixedUpdate which is where you should do all the physics, not Update (just use it for Input capture)